# TYPO3. Notify Admin on creation of new records in the backend

Tags: insert, notifications, typo3

My extension needs to notify the main `admin` every time any `user` creates a new record in the backend.

When an admin logs in to his/her backend, a notification should be displayed.

For this I need to know where the does the control move from the TCA forms after saving ?

Typo3 Version 6.1.1. Extension is built on extension builder.

Comment: Look at ``TCEmain`` for hooks.

Answer (score 1):

`sys_log` table collects that data already, so you can just write a small BE module, which will display filtered events to the admin.